# How to apply a custom skin to WP_Editor / TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I'm trying to apply a skin to a custom `wp_editor()`, but it does not seem to apply whatever I do.

The skin is generated from the TinyMCE LESS files, per instructions on https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-skin/

In my theme's folder I have a folder called `/css/tinymce` containing the following files:

> *content.inline.min.less*
>
> *content.min.less*
>
> *skin.min.less*

This is how I'm calling wp_editor, with the `skin_url` setting for TinyMCE, but it does not seem to apply the skin.

```
$settings = array(
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'textarea_rows' => 1,
    'quicktags' => false,

    'tinymce' => array(
        'toolbar1' => 'bold,italic,undo,redo',
        'statusbar' => false,

        'resize' => 'both',

        'paste_as_text' => true,

        'skin_url' => get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/tinymce'
    )
);

echo wp_editor('', 'custom_editor, $settings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the default WordPress style files overwrite a custom TinyMCE skin. So what you need to do is deregister WordPress's TinyMCE skin.

Since I needed the custom skin to only apply on the front-end on my website, I wrapped it inside an `!is_admin()` conditional.

```
function remove_editor_buttons_style() {

    // If not on wp-admin
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_deregister_style( 'editor-buttons' );
    }

} add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_editor_buttons_style' );
```