# Loading a self-hosted custom @font-face into TinyMCE dropdowns (Classic Editor) via 'tiny_mce_before_init' filter

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I can't work out how to load self-hosted custom fonts for preview in the `font_formats` and 'style_formats` dropdown in TinyMCE (Classic Editor).

TinyMCE documentation shows this example for loading a Google Fonts stylesheet
(https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-custom-font-family/):

```
tinymce.init({
  /* ... */
  content_style:
    "@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap'); body { font-family: Oswald; }",
});
```

…but when I try to apply this method to load @font-face instead, the dropdown previews still use fallback fonts. I can tell that TinyMCE is at least loading them somewhere, because if I use an incorrect path, I get a 404 error.

Example functions.php code:

```
function my_tinyMCE_init($init){
  // Works: customizes which fonts display in font_formats dropdown
  $init['font_formats'] = 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Georgia=georgia,serif;DIN=din,helvetica,sans-serif;Freight Macro=freight,serif;Lydia=lydia,sans-serif;Druk=druk,arial black,sans-serif;';
  
  // Works: customizes style_formats menu)
  $style_formats = [  
    // (arrays of basic and custom style formats here)
  ];
  $init['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );  

  // DOESN'T WORK: load font files into TinyMCE so they preview correctly in above menus
  $init['content_style'] = "@font-face{font-family:'freight';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url('".get_template_directory_uri()."/fonts/freight/FreightMacroProBookRegular/font.woff2') format('woff2'),url('".get_template_directory_uri()."/fonts/freight/FreightMacroProBookRegular/font.woff') format('woff')}";

  return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tinyMCE_init');
```

For extra clarification: I am **not** seeking to load the custom fonts for preview in the WYSIWYG editor iframe itself — that already works through the loaded editor-styles.css stylesheet. It's only the Style Formats and Font Formats dropdowns in the toolbar that don't load the fonts. Though, on that note, I also did try to just @import that stylesheet again through `['content_style']` to see if it would work for the dropdowns (as it contains all of the @font-face declarations), but that also does not work.

[image: example of desired vs actual outcome]

Comment: so you're trying to change the font face declaration when the user chooses a different style/font in the dropdown? I don't think that's feasible, you'll want to load all possible fonts, or do it using pure javascript

Comment: No, I'm trying to make the @font-face declarations available to the toolbar dropdowns when TinyMCE is initialized so the select lists (which show a preview of the font/style) show the actual custom font instead of the fallback, like the docs linked to above — Oswald is the actual font displayed in the the select lists. I want to do that exact thing, but with locally hosted fonts.

e.g. `Lydia=lydia,sans-serif;`: But the preview in the dropdown displays the `sans-serif` fallback font instead of `lydia`. In the TinyMCE example,  `Oswald` is actually displayed in the select list dropdowns.

Comment: @Tom J Nowell — Added an image that I think should help clarify.

Comment: I see, then why not also load the fontface outside too in WP Admin when on the classic editor page?

Comment: That't the thing I just can't seem to reconcile — I am already loading an editor-styles.css stylesheet through the `admin_init` action (which contains the same @font-face declarations I'm attempting here). Which you think would be enough. That stylesheet works as expected in the editor body (fonts and all other styles are reflected accurately there). And in the dropdowns, styles from editor-styles I'd expect to see — such as font-size and text-transform — are reflected in the dropdown previews as well, the only thing that isn't is the actual font-face.

Answer (score 1):

this might be too late for you but this is how I solved it:

I had the exact same problem where I could load a custom font in `editor-styles.css` and get it to appear within the TinyMCE content editor, but I couldn't get it to appear in the TinyMCE dropdown menu (select menu) options.

The fix was to add the custom font CSS with `admin_enqueue_scripts`.

Like so:

```
function admin_custom_fonts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-admin', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin.css', array(), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/admin.css' ) ); // The filemtime part helps with version control but you can skip it.
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_custom_fonts_styles', 99 );
```

And then I added my custom `@font-face` rules and custom `font-family` declarations within `admin.css` in the theme's root folder, and I could then see my custom fonts within the Tiny MCE select field options, like so:

[image: custom fonts in TinyMCE select menu options]

It might also help to note that in some cases, the default TinyMCE "skin" might cause conflicts with your custom font styling, so you might also need to add a function like this to remove the default skin:

```
// Modified from solution in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/277496/191932 to apply to the admin area
function remove_editor_buttons_style() {

    // In wp-admin, remove TinyMCE skin because it overrides some styling
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        wp_deregister_style( 'editor-buttons' );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_editor_buttons_style' );
```

I hope that helps!